# Can't echo different from each row

Tags: php, sql

I am attempting to echo a piece of information from a database. Each row has a different value and i need to be able to echo each value. I am having some trouble doing so. I had got this working before but now i just get get it.

```
$query = "SELECT itemName,defIndex,maxAmount,sellPrice,buyPrice,stock,image,type FROM priceStorage ORDER BY `itemname` ASC";
$result = mysqli_query($con,$query);
$resultSet = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_BOTH);
foreach ($resultSet as $id => $row) {
    echo $row["itemName"];
}
```

I know it is probably something stupid, but i have been trying to figure it out for a couple of hours and just can't.

Comment: Please elaborate. What's not working?

Comment: Can you check `print_r($resultSet)` if value is null or not..and also check itemName is same as column name of your table..! Or else you can use while loop statement..

Comment: The issue i am having is that no values are being echoed.

Comment: Alright, i will check.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [docs](http://php.net/manual/de/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php):

> Fetch a result row as an associative, a numeric array, or both

`mysqli_fetch_array` fetchs one row, you should do something like:

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_BOTH)) {
  echo $row['itemName'];
}
```

In this way all the rows are fetched in the while loop and echoed, you can also iterate the row values with `foreach` if that's what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Use `while` instead:

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_BOTH)) {
    echo $row['itemName'];
}
```

When you call a `mysqli_fetch` on your result, it only returns a single entry to the result. Using `while` will move that pointer along your result set array and return each `row` in turn as an associative array

Comment: Thank you ever so much, it works perfect. Thank you.